# Ruby. Can I alias the if method?

Tags: ruby

I want to do something as simple as

```
alias set_then_do if
```

because

```
if x=true
    puts "x is #{x}"
end
```

works.  But everyone who looks at the code will instinctively want to change the single equals symbol to two ( '='  to '==' ).  Just because of the if word.  But I want the assignment to be there without confusing the code reader.  So I want something like the following:

```
alias set_then_do if

set_then_do x=true
    puts "x is #{x}"
end
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

---

To answer the question why; here is my sample case.

```
if http.use_ssl = @use_ssl # ASSIGNMENT! NOT TESTING EQUALITY!
     http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
     http.verify_depth = 9
end
```

---

This fits my aesthetics:

```
http.use_ssl = @use_ssl; if @use_ssl
     http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
     http.verify_depth = 9
end
```

I'm still open to an answer to aliasing the if method ^_^

Comment: **Why oh why** would you write it that way instead of `x = true`, then `puts "x is #{x}"` on a second line at the same level?

Comment: What is the point of testing if true is true ?

Comment: I'm actually using it to set multiple values.  But the assignment being on a different line doesn't look aesthetically pleasing in my code.

Comment: Your "sample case" is less mind-bogglingly redundant, but it's still not worth the potential confusion, let alone introducing special syntax simply to avoid that confusion (but probably replacing it with *other* confusion). Plus, `set_then_do` is a bad name since it implies the block is always executed. Just freaking write the assignment on a separate line, it's not that hard. Just alter your sense of aesthetics ;-)

Comment: True.  I was hoping there was a clean way to do this.  And yes, maybe the name isn't the best. :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if` is not a method; it's a keyword. Ruby doesn't provide any facilities for modifying its syntax, so you can't do this.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with a disclaimer that I don't recommend doing this. However, as Chuck points you can't do what you want, but you can get "close".

Also, I agree `set_then_do` is a poor name and you might want a different one. Maybe `do_if` instead.

Having said all that, you can in the global name space make the following function:

```
def do_if(val, &block)
  yield if val
end
```

Then where you want to use it you can do:

```
do_if(http.use_ssl = @use_ssl) do
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  http.verify_depth = 9
end
```

Again, I wouldn't recommend any of that, but it does come close to what you are looking for.